# Datomic - Setting Up a Free transactor integrated storage

Tags: datomic

I want to set up a Free transactor integrated storage datomic database.

I am confused about what a transactor integrated storage actually is and struggling to set this up.

From some research I know I need to set a transactor on my computer and then use that for the connection, with the connection being `datomic:free://{transactor-host}:{port}/{db-name}`. The transactor-host would be `localhost:3300` so my connection would be something like `datomic:free://localhost:3300/mydb`. But I am not getting a connection.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure what's causing the issue since you haven't included an error message or anything similar, but there are a couple gotchas:

1. You need to call `(datomic/create-database connection-string)` before calling `(datomic/connection connection-string)`.  This was counterintuitive to me when starting out.
2. The transactor defaults to port 4334, but also (**for the free transactor only**) needs access to the two ports above (4335 and 4336 by default), so make sure all of those ports aren't being blocked by a firewall or similar.